# ? is Optional<T> under the hood, what about implicitly unwrapped optional - is there a representation for it?

Tags: swift

In Swift, under the hood a variable of type T? is equivalent to

```
Optional<T>
```

Is there a representation for implicitly unwrapped optional of T?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
enum ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T> : LogicValue, Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible
```